# removeClass doesn't work for two elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, removeclass

I have a nested un-ordered list like this:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
            <li id="about"><a href="/"  class="active">About</a></li>
            <li id="categories" class="hide"><a id="parent" href="../" >Projects</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="/kalaja">Hotel Kalaja</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/alfer">Alfer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/xani">Xani Triko</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/leka">Leka Gas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/tuni">Tuni Plast</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/visari">Visari AM</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            <li id="personal" class="hide"><a href="#" id="parent">Personal</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="/film">Film</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/glitch">Glitch</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

with the CSS set to hide the child list

```
li {
max-height: 115px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.4s;
}
.hide { max-height: 15px;}
```

And then the jquery to remove thie .hide class from the parent, so the child list can be visible

```
$('#parent').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hide');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('#parent').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

The problem is that the code works for the first `<li>` with the `categories` id, but doesn't work for the `<li>` with the `personal` id.

Comment: You have two `id="parent"`. This is not possible. **ID must be unique within the DOM**.

Comment: Element `id` must be unique within document.

Comment: Very dumb of me, thank you all.

Comment: This happens a lot more than you would think. No worries here :)

Comment: Question to admins or whoever has more experience: Since this was such a mistake with a fast and very simple solution, should I just delete it, or wait and selected the appropriate answer ?

Comment: Usually, simple questions like this one are closed as a duplicate of an older one with more complete answers. As I can't find one, feel free to accept whatever answer you want (usually the one whom author was the quickest to spot your mistake ;-)). Thanks for caring so much about how the system works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, IDs should be unique. Change your ids to classes.

```
$('.parent').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hide');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('.parent').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `id` with the same value within the DOM. Therefore, you would need to change to classes for it to work:

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li id="about"><a href="/"  class="active">About</a></li>
    <li id="categories" class="hide"><a class="parent" href="../" >Projects</a> <!-- note the class instead of id -->
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="/kalaja">Hotel Kalaja</a></li>
            <li><a href="/alfer">Alfer</a></li>
            <li><a href="/xani">Xani Triko</a></li>
            <li><a href="/leka">Leka Gas</a></li>
            <li><a href="/tuni">Tuni Plast</a></li>
            <li><a href="/visari">Visari AM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="personal" class="hide"><a href="#" class="parent">Personal</a>  <!-- note the class instead of id -->
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="/film">Film</a></li>
            <li><a href="/glitch">Glitch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('.parent').mouseover(function() { // note the . instead of #
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hide');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('.parent').mouseout(function() { // note the . instead of #
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.parent').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hide');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('.parent').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
li {
max-height: 115px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.4s;
}
.hide { max-height: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-list">
            <li id="about"><a href="/"  class="active">About</a></li>
            <li id="categories" class="hide"><a class="parent" href="../" >Projects</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="/kalaja">Hotel Kalaja</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/alfer">Alfer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/xani">Xani Triko</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/leka">Leka Gas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/tuni">Tuni Plast</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/visari">Visari AM</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            <li id="personal" class="hide"><a href="#" class="parent">Personal</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="/film">Film</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/glitch">Glitch</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Change the `ID`'s to Classes. Then it would work. You can have only one unique id per page. So if you want to use the same identifier for different elements, make it as a class.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/y5p8Ldgd/